# Почему не срабатывает onChange в инпуте React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, react-hook

Делаю что-то вроде сайта для хранения файлов. Для их загрузки в инпуте, при выборе файлов, вызывается метод `add` из кастомного хука.

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const isDirectory = maybeFile => !maybeFile.type && maybeFile.size % 4096 === 0;

const generateId = () => (performance.now().toString(36) +
    Math.random().toString(36)).replace(/\./g, '');

export const useFiles = (initialState={}) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialState);

    const add = newFiles => {
        const filteredFiles = newFiles.filter(file => !isDirectory(file));
        const result = {};
        filteredFiles.forEach(file => {
            result[generateId()] = file;
        });
        setValue({...value, ...result});
    };

    const remove = fileId => {
        let filesCopy = {...value};
        delete filesCopy[fileId];
        setValue(filesCopy);
    };

    return {value, add, remove};
};
```

И я не могу понять, почему если загрузить несколько файлов на сайт, потом их поудалять с помощью `remove`, который срабатывает при нажатии на кнопочку удаления рядом с файлом, а потом заново попытаться загрузить эти же файлы, то `onChange` в инпуте не срабатывает. Но если выбрать какие-то другие файлы, то все сработает и опять же при их удалении их нельзя будет еще раз загрузить, но уже станет возможно предыдущие.

В консоли никаких ошибок не пишет. Дебагом не получается проверить, потому что сам `onChange` не срабатывает.

**Еще небольшое пояснение:**

Вот эти файлы из хука отрисовываются с помощью компонента файла в `map` и внутри этого компонента я использую еще 1 кастомный хук, в котором более удобно хранятся id файла и сам файл. Может ли быть проблема в этом возможно лишнем хуке?

```
import {useState} from "react";

export const useFile = (fileId, file) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(file);
    const [id, setId] = useState(fileId);

    return {value, id};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Так и не понял в чем проблема, но попробовал заменить эти 2 хука на useReducer и все стало отлично работать

```
import React, {useReducer, createContext} from 'react';
import {reducer} from './reducer';

const filesToExpand = ['text/plain', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png',
    'video/mp4', 'video/mov', 'video/ogv', 'video/webm'];

export const FilesContext = createContext(null);

export const Provider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);

    const value = {
        files: state,
        add: file => dispatch({
            type: 'add',
            payload: {
                value: file,
                canShow: filesToExpand.includes(file.type),
                hidden: true
            }
        }),
        remove: id => dispatch({
            type: 'remove',
            payload: {id: id}
        })
    };

    return (
        <FilesContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</FilesContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

```
const generateId = () => (performance.now().toString(36) +
    Math.random().toString(36)).replace(/\./g, '');

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    const payload = action.payload;

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add':
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: generateId(),
                    value: payload.value,
                    canShow: payload.canShow,
                    hidden: payload.hidden,
                }
            ];
        case 'remove':
            return [...state.filter(file => file.id !== payload.id)];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```